# Array Fetching time one row value is skipping by code

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

In php code i tried to fetch data from my database but when i fetch data two times or one time the next time the output of code is skipping first value in my output ..

```
$result = mysql_query($order) or die(mysql_error());

echo mysql_num_rows($result);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo ("<tr><td>$row[name]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[email]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[address]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}
```

What the reason of this ..

Comment: your question is confusing. can you elaborate this:-`but when i fetch data two times or one time the next time the output of code is skipping first value in my output .`

Comment: also show us the sql query??

Comment: I would really recommend you, to not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and would be removed in later versions of `PHP`

Comment: check your code. i gave a comment there. try that and tell works for you or not? `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);//remove this line and you get solution`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.The only thing to do is just remove the first assignment of mysql_fetch_array($result).

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Just remove this assignment and then run your code.It will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` twice

The first time the $row variable contains the first row.

The second time you are looping trough all rows, but because you already fetched the first row, it is not looping trough that row again.

The solution is: Remove the first call to `mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Answer (score 1):

Delete your first statement that says:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The above statement takes the next row from your query and stores it as an array in the variable $row. However, since you have a while loop that is also doing the same thing every time the loop is run, it overwrites the old value in $row with the next row available. So the first time you enter the loop your first row gets erased. Deleting the above line will solve this for you.

Answer (score 0):

because, as describe here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the
>   internal data pointer ahead.

So by calling the function a first time

```
 // else{echo "false";}
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 // echo mysql_num_rows($row);
```

you are moving the pointer ahead, so when you call the function in your while loop

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo ("<tr><td>$row[name]</td>");
  echo ("<td>$row[email]</td>");
  echo ("<td>$row[address]</td>");
  echo ("<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td></tr>");
}
```

the pointer has already moved forward.

To fix your issue, remove the first `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` and only keep the one in your while loop.

Comment: Also, as many will tell you, consider updating your code to use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_*. I know it can be alot of work...